# Intuition behind the relation between eigenvalues, determinant, and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been trying to find a formal definition for the determinant and trace without the ugly case-by-case hard coded formulas or index references.

What I've found so far is $det(A) = \prod_i \lambda_i$ and $tr(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i$ where $\lambda$'s are the eigenvalues of the operator. These are really nice definitions but I'm having a hard time in deciphering its meaning. How should I interpret these quantities in relation to the eigenvalues?

Edit:
Also, if there are two eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue, will there be 2 occurrences of the same eigenvalue in the calculation of $det/tr$?

Comment: To answer the question in your edit, yes.  In the formulae $det(A) = \prod_i \lambda_i$ $tr(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i$ you count the eigenvalues *with multiplicity*, i.e., if the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ has dimension $k$, then $k$ of the multiplicands (resp. summands) in the expression $\prod_i \lambda_i$ (resp. $\sum_i \lambda_i$) should be $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The column vectors in the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ form the sides eminating from one vertex of an $n$-dimensional parallelepiped. These vectors determine the entire parallelepiped. The determinant is a signed $n$-volume for that parallelepiped. This defines the determinant up to the sign, and provides a nice geometric feel for the determinant. In particular, if the vectors are not linearly independent, then one of the vectors lies in the hyper-plane determined by the rest, making the parallelepiped flat, and so having zero volume.

However, how the sign fits into this is not clear. It can be defined by carefully defining which permutations should have positive sign and which are negative, but is it hard to justify why it should be that way.

Another definition is algebraic and fully defines the determinant in a natural fashion. It can also be explained by the wedge product, however that requires more development than this:

If $V$ is a vector space over the field $\Bbb F$, then a function $F: V^k \to \Bbb F$ is multi-linear if $F$ is linear in each of its arguments. That is, for all $a, b \in \Bbb F$ and $\{v_i\} \subset V, v \in V$ and indexes $i$, $$F(v_1, ..., v_{i-1}, av_i + bv, v_{i+1}, ..., v_k) =\\ aF(v_1, ..., v_{i-1}, v_i, v_{i+1}, ..., v_k) + bF(v_1, ..., v_{i-1}, v, v_{i+1}, ..., v_k)$$

$F$ is called *alternating* if exchanging any two arguments changes the sign: for all $i,j$, $$F(...,v_i,...,v_j...) = -F(...,v_j, ..., v_i, ...)$$

If $F, G$ are two alternating multilinear functions on $V^k$, and $a,b \in \Bbb F$, then it is easy to see that $aF + bG$ is also an alternating multilinear function. Therefore the set $A_k(V)$ of all alternating multilinear functions on $V^k$ is itself a vector space. If $V$ is of dimension $n$, then it can be shown that $A_k(V)$ has dimension $n \choose k$. In particular the dimension of $A_n(V)$ is $1$.

If $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation, and $F \in A_k(V)$, then $F(T, ..., T) : (v_1, ... v_k) \mapsto F(Tv_1, ... Tv_n)$ is also in $A_k(V)$ and depends linearly on $F$:
$$(aF + bG)(T, ..., T) = aF(T, ..., T) + bG(T, ...,T)$$
Thus $T$ induces a linear transformation $T^{(k)}$ on $A_k(V): T^{(k)}(F) = F(T, ..., T)$

Since $A_n(V)$ is one-dimensional, linear transformations on it are just multiplication by a scalar constant. The determinant of $T$ is defined to be the constant that $T^{(n)}$ multiplies by.

More concisely, for a linear transformation $T$ on an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$, $\det T$ is the unique scalar such that for any alternating multilinear function $F$ on $V^n$, $$F(T, ..., T) = (\det T)F$$

I am not aware of a similar natural definition for the trace, other than
$$tr(T) = \left .\frac {d}{dt}\right |_{t=0} \det(I + tT)$$

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, is it correct to say that the eigenvectors are collinear to the parallelepiped edges and the eigenvalues are the lengths? Thus, the volume is just the product of the lengths?
Edit: And the edges must also have a direction as well to keep track of the signs.

Comment: No, the eigenvectors are coparallel to the edges only when $A$ is a diagonal matrix (in which case, the eigenvalues are indeed the lengths). In general, eigenvectors are difficult to find. If they were just the column vectors, they would be easy!

Comment: Oh yes, I see. The diagonal case is indeed what I had in mind but I wrongly assumed that it works generally.